# Explanation of Text on Threading in "C# 3.0 in a Nutshell"

Tags: multithreading, wait, waithandle, pulse

While reading ***C# 3.0 in a Nutshell*** by *Joseph and Ben Albahari*, I came across the following paragraph (page 673, first paragraph in section titled "**Signaling with Wait and Pulse**")

> "The **Monitor** class provides another signalling construct via two static methods, **Wait** and **Pulse**. The principle is that you write the signalling logic yourself using custom flags and fields (enclosed in **lock** statements), and then introduce **Wait** and **Pulse** commands to mitigate CPU spinning. The advantage of this low-level approach is that with just **Wait**, **Pulse**, and the **lock** statement, you can achieve the functionality of **AutoResetEvent**, **ManualResetEvent**, and **Semaphore**, as well as **WaitHandle**'s static methods **WaitAll** and **WaitAny**.  Furthermore, **Wait** and **Pulse**
>   can be amenable in situations where
>   all of the wait handles are
>   parsimoniously challenged."

My question is, what is the correct interpretation of the *last* sentence?

- A situation with a decent/large number of wait handles where WaitOne() is only occasionally called on any particular wait handle.
- A situation with a decent/large number of wait handles where rarely does more than one thread tend to block on any particular wait handle.
- Some other interpretation.

Would also appreciate illuminating examples of such situations and perhaps how and/or why they are more efficiently handled via Wait and Pulse rather than by other methods.

Thank you!

Edit: I found the text online [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse)

Comment: You need to bring in more context, since not all who read your question have read the book, too.

Comment: Perhaps Joe Albahari might be watching...

Comment: @Vlad done!
@Mitch mmm, I can hope :)

Comment: BTW, the fourth edition, "C# 4.0 in a Nutshell" was recently released...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What this is saying is that there are some situations where Wait and Pulse provides a simpler solution than wait handles. In general, this happens where:

- The waiter, rather than the notifier, decides when to unblock
- The blocking condition involves more than a simple flag (perhaps several variables)

You can still use wait handles in these situations, but Wait/Pulse tends to be simpler. The great thing about Wait/Pulse is that Wait releases the underlying lock while waiting. For instance, in the following example, we're reading _x and _y within the safety of a lock - and yet that lock is released while waiting so that another thread can update those variables:

```
lock (_locker)
{
  while (_x < 10 && _y < 20) Monitor.Wait (_locker);
}
```

Another thread can then update _x and _y atomically (by virtue of the lock) and then Pulse to signal the waiter:

```
lock (_locker)
{
  _x = 20;
  _y = 30;
  Monitor.Pulse (_locker);
}
```

The disadvantage of Wait/Pulse is that it's easier to get it wrong and make a mistake (for instance, by updating a variable and forgetting to Pulse). In situations where a program with wait handles is equally simple to a program with Wait/Pulse, I'd recommend going with wait handles for that reason.

In terms of efficiency/resource consumption (which I think you were alluding to), Wait/Pulse is usually faster and lighter (as it has a managed implementation). This is rarely a big deal in practice, though. And on that point, Framework 4.0 includes low-overhead managed versions of ManualResetEvent and Semaphore (ManualResetEventSlim and SemaphoreSlim).

Framework 4.0 also provides many more synchronization options that lessen the need for Wait/Pulse:

- CountdownEvent
- Barrier
- PLINQ / Data Parallelism (AsParallel, Parallel.Invoke, Parallel.For, Parallel.ForEach)
- Tasks and continuations

All of these are much higher-level than Wait/Pulse and IMO are preferable for writing reliable and maintainable code (assuming they'll solve the task at hand).

Comment: Just a guess...but you seem to have the inside track on what the author might have meant :)
Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry - I should have said that I'm the author of the article :)